How to do binomial glm in R for presence of porpoise related to depth?



Depth.
presence




8
0


31
1.


31
1


29
0



This is just a few lines from the data. There's about a couple hundred data points . With 1 indicating presence at a certain depth and 0 is absence
data< read.csv(presence.data.csv, header=TRUE)
M1<glm(presence~depth,   family=binomial)
x<-seq(min(data$depth), max(data$depth), length.out=100
y<- predict(M1, list(depth=x), type=response)
plot(data$depth,data$presence, PCH=16)


I'm not sure if this code is correct as have read different variations but I need to use bimonial glm
From that code I made a plot however it won't led me add a photo


Your first 2 assignments are wrong, they are not arrows <-; 2) you are missing the data argument in glm(presence~depth,   family=binomial).


Are you sure your presence column is numeric? It looks like one of the values includes a period.
